# .htaccess redirect from folder to file with variable

Tags: .htaccess

I'm wondering how I can redirect this:

```
sample.com/issues/3
sample.com/issues/4
etc.
```

to

```
sample.com/issues/index.php?id=3
sample.com/issues/index.php?id=4
etc.
```

**UPDATE:** A friend suggested this:

```
RewriteRule ^issues/(.*)$ issues/index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

But this redirects to the wrong subdirectory. E.g. it redirects /issues/4/ to /issues/4/?id=4

Strangely it seems to check out on this [testing site](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=30c71897-2b7b-5035-9912-a7a8080f6967) but it's not working on my local server, nor on my live server.

Any ideas? The full .htaccess now looks like so:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sample.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.sample.com/$1 [L,R=301]

Redirect /archive.php /issues/

RewriteRule ^issues/(.*)$ issues/index.php?issue=$1 [L]
```

Comment: See above. Still no luck. 

Answer (score 0):

Create a new `.htaccess` inside `issues/` directory with this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?issue=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks. Do I keep the above code in the .htaccess file in the root directory? Update: with the original .htaccess in the root and your suggested .htaccess in the 'issues' folder, nothing happens. It just loads sample.com/issues/3 as usual.

Comment: Yes, I'm just asking if you want me to remove anything from the .htaccess file in the root directory? If I leave as is and add your .htaccess file to the /issues/ folder as you suggested, the browser simply loads sample.com/issues/3 with no apparent redirect happening at all.

Comment: That error is coming from your PHP code due to include path issue. For a browser and web server a valid issue URL `https://www.densediscovery.com/issues/2/` is loading same as invalid issue URL i.e.`https://www.densediscovery.com/issues/20/` . Note that you need trailing slash for all these URLs.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I think I'm too far out of my depth now. Will have to hire someone to get this working. Cheers

Comment: Use this answer to fix your include path: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8726898/using-htaccess-to-rewrite-paths-to-php-includes